# non-blocking producer and consumer using .NET 2.0

Tags: multithreading, c#-2.0

In our scenario,

- the consumer takes at least half-a-second to complete a cycle of process (against a row in a data table).
- Producer produces at least 8 items in a second (no worries, we don't mind about the duration of a consuming).
- the shared data is simply a data table.
- we should never ask producer to wait (as it is a server and we don't want it to wait on this)

How can we achieve the above without locking the data table at all (as we don't want producer to wait in any way).

We cannot use .NET 4.0 yet in our org.

Comment: Since the times of processing are different..Can't you use an intermediate table for the producer to put the produced data?

Comment: data table = `System.Data.DataTable` correct?

Comment: Jake, yes it is System.Data.DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great example of a producer/consumer queue using Monitors at [this page](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) under the "Producer/Consumer Queue" section.  In order to synchronize access to the underlying data table, you can have a single consumer.

That page is probably the best resource for threading in .NET on the net.

Comment: This doesn't address his requirement to never lock his `DataTable`.

Comment: I was under the impression from the description that the DataTable wasn't shared between producers and consumers, it was only shared between consumers.  If that assumption is false, then this solution won't work.

Comment: Chuu, at some point, I still have to clear DataTable in a meaningful manner I guess.  Otherwise, I will end up with huge data at the client.

Comment: You could always use a Producer/Consumer queue to serialize everything, i.e. both Producers and Consumers as "Producers", and the Action<> you enqueue onto the queue is dequeued by a single "Consumer" and executed.  You are going to lose any benefits to multiple cores, but you will not have any locks around your Datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a buffer that holds the data while it is being processed.

It takes you half a second to process, and you get 8 items a second... unless you have at least 4 processors working on it, you'll have a problem.

Just to be safe I'd use a buffer at least twice the side needed (16 rows), and make sure it's possible with the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet that is going to let you access a `DataTable` from multiple threads without using a blocking synchronization mechanism. What I would do is to hold the lock for as short a duration as possible. Keep in mind that modifying any object in the data table's hierarchy will require locking the whole data table. This is because modifying a column value on a `DataRow` *can* change the internal indexing structures inside the parent `DataTable`.

So what I would do is from the producer acquire a lock, add a new row, and release the lock. Then in the conumser you will acquire the same lock, copy data contained in a `DataRow` into a separate data structure, and then release the lock immediately. Now, you can operate on the copied data without synchronization mechanisms since it is isolated. After you have completed the operation on it you will again acquire the lock, merge the changes back into the `DataRow`, and then release the lock and start the process all over again.

Comment: I already thought in the same manner.  But, I could not convince our guys on locking the producer (not even for a nano second).  Any way, thanks for your advice.